# Configuring a build file for a .NET solution to be used by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to configure a .build file for a solution which will be built by Jenkins.
The solutions builds properly but Jenkins takes forever to create an installer for the same.
Here is the file currently in use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="SampleApp" default="Install"      xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/schemas/nant.xsd" >
<property name="basename" value="SampleApp"/>
<property name ="jenkinshome" value ="C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\" />
<property name="OutputPath" value="bin/Release"/>
<property name="Release" value="true"/>
<property name="SampleApp.exe.config" value="Release" />
<property name="SolutionFileName" value = "SampleApp.sln" />
<property name="TargetFramework" value="${framework::get-target-framework()}" />
<target name="clean">
<delete>
  <fileset>
    <include name="${OutputPath}/${basename}.exe"/>
    <include name="${OutputPath}/${basename}.pdb"/>
  </fileset>
 </delete>
</target>

<target name="build" >
<mkdir dir="${OutputPath}" />
<echo message= "${framework::get-assembly-directory(TargetFramework)}" />
<exec program="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe"
          commandline=''
            workingdir="." />
</target>

<target name ="Install" depends="build">
<exec program="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe">
  <arg value ="C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Legacy Data         Adapter\workspace\SampleApp\SampleApp.vdproj /rebuild Release">
  </arg>
</exec>

</target>

</project>
```

I am new to Jenkins and the whole concept of CI.
Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

got a lot of help from here [Anatomy of a build file](http://mutelight.org/articles/the-anatomy-of-a-nant-build-file)

Solved.

Regards.